# Automatically removing associations when deleting entities in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

I have the following entities:

```
namespace NhLists {
  public class Lesson {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
  }
  public class Module {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public Module() {
      Lessons = new List<Lesson>();
    }
  }
}
```

And the following mappings:

```
<class name="Module" table="Modules">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <list name="Lessons" table="ModuleToLesson"
      cascade="save-update">
    <key column="moduleId"/>
    <index column="position"/>
    <many-to-many 
      column="lessonId" 
      class="NhLists.Lesson, NhLists"/>
  </list>
</class>
<class name="Lesson" table="Lessons">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="identity"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Title">
    <column name="Title" length="16" not-null="true" />
  </property>
</class>
```

When I delete a lesson by `session.Delete(lesson)`, is there anyway I can have NHibernate automatically update the association in `Module.Lessons` to remove the entry from the set? Or am I forced to go through all Modules and look for the lesson and remove that by hand?

Edit: Fixed `ICollection` and `<set>` in mappings to `IList<>` and `<list>` like I want and tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have false idea. If you want to delete the Lesson object from `Module` you do that manually. NHibernate just tracks such your action and when `session.Commit()` is called then the reference between `Module` and `Lesson` is deleted in the database.

Calling `session.Delete(lesson)` deletes the lesson object from database (if foreign keys are set properly then reference between `Module` and `Lesson` is deleted of course but it is not responsibility for NHibernate).

In conclusion, it is not possible to delete the lesson object from the `Module.Lessons` list automatically by calling `session.Delete(lesson)`. NHibernate does not track such entity references.

Comment: Ok, so what tricked me was that it's actually the database that clears the reference (by way of the FK) and not NHibernate? That seems a reasonable explanation to the behavour I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that if we do not need IList semantics and can make do with ICollection the update problem can be solved by adding a reference back from Lesson to Module, such as:

```
public class Lesson {
  ...
  protected virtual ICollection<Module> InModules { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

And to the mapping files add:

```
<class name="Lesson" table="Lessons">
  ...
  <set name="InModules" table="ModuleToLesson">
    <key column="lessonId"/>
    <many-to-many column="moduleId" class="NhLists.Module, NhLists"/>
  </set>
</class>
```

Then a `Lesson` deleted is also removed from the collection in `Module` automatically. This also works for lists but the list index is not properly updated and causes "holes" in the list.